# Calling function by its name as string

Tags: c++, reflection

Is it possible to call a method by its name as string?

```
#define callmethod(function) \
this->#function();
```

Just a simple example. (it doesn't work).

```
callmethod("myfunction");
```

> error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Comment: the short answer: no. the long answer: it can be done by reflection in java/c#. i don't know about c++ so i don't post an answer

Comment: The `#` preprocessor operator is the *stringify* operator, i.e. it converts the arguments symbol *to* a string, not the other way around.

Comment: And no, it's can't generally be done in C++. You *can* make a `std::map` which maps strings to (e.g.) [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects.

Comment: Not sure - never tried or saw anything (not yet).

Comment: You need to make a map with function names and pointers.

Comment: Maybe you could cook something up with the preprocessor stringify operator mentioned above, and dlopen()/dlsym(), at least on Linux. Look at 'man dlsym'.